# Loading data set

Tags: r

I am getting the following error message:

> Error in get0(oNam, envir = ns) :    lazy-load database 'D:/R/R-3.4.3/library/yaml/R/yaml.rdb' is corrupt
>
> In addition: Warning message: In get0(oNam, envir = ns) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
>
> Error in get0(oNam, envir = ns) :    lazy-load database 'D:/R/R-3.4.3/library/yaml/R/yaml.rdb' is corrupt
>
> In addition: Warning messages: 1: In get0(oNam, envir = ns) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation 2: In get0(oNam, envir = ns) : internal error -3 in R_decompress

I was not able to load my data set for analysis. If anyone is able to help please let me know.

Comment: "Lazy Loading" is not a programming language. What language is this code in? For that matter, what is the code?

Comment: It is R, R studio. wheneever i opened the R studio this messages comes. lazy-load database 'D:/R/R-3.4.3/library/yaml/R/yaml.rdb' is corrupt

Comment: I've retagged it as R. It would help if you add some code that helps us reproduce this problem.

Comment: maybe `remove.packages("yaml")` and reopen your RStudio?

Comment: Dear chinsoo, I did as you suggested but remains the same.

Comment: Does it affect anything you're doing?

Comment: yes Rohit, i could not run the packages

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who runs across the same problem---I have experienced it under RHEL 7.6 Linux 3.10.0-957.e17.x86_64. The following was the message that I got, when I was updating and re-installing my own package:

> lazy-load database '/home/user/R/library/callr/R/callr.rdb' is corrupt
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In get0(oNam, envir = ns) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
>
> 2: In get0(oNam, envir = ns) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1

I tried

```
install.packages("callr")
```

and installing my package again (via `devtools::install_github`) but it did not work. Ultimately I did `remove.packages("mypackage")` and then quit the session, restarted, and installed. It worked.

I know that the original user said it didn't work for him, so perhaps it was a OS specific issue---but this is for future users who will run across the same problem. It may have been that the original user was working in Windows and had other R sessions open when he tried `remove.packages`.